# Should nested runnables be avoided in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a function to programatically display messages in a scroll view by adding  textviews to the linearlayout in it.
I want it to be inside a handler.post, and also want the scrollview to automatically scroll to the bottom of the scrollview every time a message is added.

Here is the code:

```
public void addMsg(final String msg) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView newText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            newText.setText(msg);
            linLayout.addView(newText);
            scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Is it bad convention to do this? Is there another way to accomplish this without nested runnables  if it is bad to do?

Comment: No, but now try rotating the screen.

Comment: The textviews disappear. So then to fix that would I just do the usual steps required when saving stuff on rotate, or would this double runnable complicate things? @EpicPandaForce